# Kafka Streams Split 1 Stream in Multiple Stream

Tags: java, json, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I got a Projekt to learn working with Kafka Streams, but I have really trouble with it. I am working on kafka-streams version 1.0.1. 
We have a Main Topic Stream with Messages with the following Style:

```
{
    "phenomenonTime" : "2017-04-03T16:08:19.000Z",
    "resultTime" : "2017-04-03T16:08:19.000Z",
    "result" : {
      "Temperature" : 0,
      "Pressure" : 0,
      "Humidity" : 0,
      "Mean altitude" : 0,
      "Mass PM2.5" : 7.4,
      "Mass Error PM2.5" : 1.5,
      "Mass PM10" : 12.3,
      "Mass Error PM10" : 1.5
    }
  }
```

It's a Json Format, there is my first Probleme, I dont know how exactly use the Json Deserializer or Serializer.

But my Main Target is to create the Topics Temperature,Pressure,Humidity,Mean altitude... out of the Main Topic his Result Field with the right values in the Temperature Topic.

How can I realise that with Kafka Streams? 
I hope you can help me, to get better started with Kafka Streams.

EDIT:

Hole Message + key (formatted)

```
    Key c45e9532-9810-11e8-8839-03e1e3365152
    Value { "phenomenonTime" : "2017-04-03T16:08:09.000Z",
 "resultTime" : "2017-04-03T16:08:09.000Z",
 "result" : { "Temperature" : 0,
 "Pressure" : 0, 
"Humidity" : 0, 
"Mean altitude" : 0, 
"Mass PM2.5" : 7.1,
 "Mass Error PM2.5" : 1.5,
 "Mass PM10" : 9.6, "Mass Error PM10" : 1.5 },
 "Datastream@iot.navigationLink" : "http://localhost:8080/FROST-Server/v1.0/Observations('c45e9532-9810-11e8-8839-03e1e3365152')/Datastream", 
"Datastream" : { "unitOfMeasurement" : { "name" : null, "symbol" : null, "definition" : null }, "@iot.id" : "geo.uni-augsburg.de/Fixed-Wing-UAV-1/Datastreams/LOAC_LOCAL_201704031605.mass" }, 
"FeatureOfInterest@iot.navigationLink" : "http://localhost:8080/FROST-Server/v1.0/Observations('c45e9532-9810-11e8-8839-03e1e3365152')/FeatureOfInterest",
 "FeatureOfInterest" : { "@iot.id" : "c458a1a4-9810-11e8-8839-176a6dbe6951" }, "@iot.id" : "c45e9532-9810-11e8-8839-03e1e3365152", "@iot.selfLink" : "http://localhost:8080/FROST-Server/v1.0/Observations('c45e9532-9810-11e8-8839-03e1e3365152')" }
```

Unformated:

```
Key c45e9532-9810-11e8-8839-03e1e3365152
Value { "phenomenonTime" : "2017-04-03T16:08:09.000Z", "resultTime" : "2017-04-03T16:08:09.000Z", "result" : { "Temperature" : 0, "Pressure" : 0, "Humidity" : 0, "Mean altitude" : 0, "Mass PM2.5" : 7.1, "Mass Error PM2.5" : 1.5, "Mass PM10" : 9.6, "Mass Error PM10" : 1.5 }, "Datastream@iot.navigationLink" : "http://localhost:8080/FROST-Server/v1.0/Observations('c45e9532-9810-11e8-8839-03e1e3365152')/Datastream", "Datastream" : { "unitOfMeasurement" : { "name" : null, "symbol" : null, "definition" : null }, "@iot.id" : "geo.uni-augsburg.de/Fixed-Wing-UAV-1/Datastreams/LOAC_LOCAL_201704031605.mass" }, "FeatureOfInterest@iot.navigationLink" : "http://localhost:8080/FROST-Server/v1.0/Observations('c45e9532-9810-11e8-8839-03e1e3365152')/FeatureOfInterest", "FeatureOfInterest" : { "@iot.id" : "c458a1a4-9810-11e8-8839-176a6dbe6951" }, "@iot.id" : "c45e9532-9810-11e8-8839-03e1e3365152", "@iot.selfLink" : "http://localhost:8080/FROST-Server/v1.0/Observations('c45e9532-9810-11e8-8839-03e1e3365152')" }
```

But the Datastream@iot.navigationLink, Datastream .... are not the Important. But the Key must be the same.

Thats how it looks exactly (https://i.stack.imgur.com/2x88k.png)

Hole exported Stream:

https://pastebin.com/PUfhL8fK

Example Kafka Client :

https://pastebin.com/y4k7fQgz

Answer (score 1):

for that you need to create multiple `KStream` objects for each required destination topic. for extracting required fields from main json, use `mapValues` method on kStream.
to simplify work with json values, you can use `JsonSerde` from `spring-kafka` library (groupId: org.springframework.kafka, artifactId: spring-kafka).

example for temperature & pressure topics (and do the same for each of required destination topics):

```
Map<String, String> streamProperties = new HashMap<>();
streamProperties.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
streamProperties.put("key.serde", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde");
streamProperties.put("value.serde", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde");

Map<String, String> streamProperties1 = new HashMap<>(streamProperties);
streamProperties1.put("application.id", "temperature");
Map<String, String> streamProperties2 = new HashMap<>(streamProperties);
streamProperties2.put("application.id", "pressure");

Class<Map<String, Object>> genericMapClass = (Class) Map.class;
Consumed<String, Map<String, Object>> consumed = Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), new JsonSerde<>(genericMapClass));
Produced<String, Map<String, Object>> produced = Produced.with(Serdes.String(), new JsonSerde<>(genericMapClass));

StreamsBuilder streamBuilder1 = new StreamsBuilder();
KStream<String, Map<String, Object>> temperatureKStream = streamBuilder1.stream("mainSourceTopic", consumed);
temperatureKStream.mapValues((generalDetails) -> {
    Object temperatureValue = ((Map) generalDetails.get("result")).get("Temperature");
    Map<String, Object> temperatureMessageDetails = new HashMap<>();
    temperatureMessageDetails.put("Temperature", temperatureValue);
    temperatureMessageDetails.put("phenomenonTime", generalDetails.get("phenomenonTime"));
    temperatureMessageDetails.put("resultTime", generalDetails.get("resultTime"));
    System.out.println("temperatureMessageDetails: " + temperatureMessageDetails);
    return temperatureMessageDetails;
}).to("temperatureTopic", produced);

StreamsBuilder streamBuilder2 = new StreamsBuilder();
KStream<String, Map<String, Object>> pressureKStream = streamBuilder2.stream("mainSourceTopic", consumed);
pressureKStream.mapValues((generalDetails) -> {
    Object pressureValue = ((Map) generalDetails.get("result")).get("Pressure");
    Map<String, Object> pressureMessageDetails = new HashMap<>();
    pressureMessageDetails.put("Pressure", pressureValue);
    pressureMessageDetails.put("phenomenonTime", generalDetails.get("phenomenonTime"));
    pressureMessageDetails.put("resultTime", generalDetails.get("resultTime"));
    System.out.println("pressureMessageDetails: " + pressureMessageDetails);
    return pressureMessageDetails;
}).to("pressureTopic", produced);

StreamsConfig streamsConfig1 = new StreamsConfig(streamProperties1);
KafkaStreams kafkaStreams1 = new KafkaStreams(streamBuilder1.build(), streamsConfig1);
kafkaStreams1.start();

StreamsConfig streamsConfig2 = new StreamsConfig(streamProperties2);
KafkaStreams kafkaStreams2 = new KafkaStreams(streamBuilder2.build(), streamsConfig2);
kafkaStreams2.start();

Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(() -> {
    kafkaStreams1.close();
    kafkaStreams2.close();
}));
```

Comment: I editet the boostrapserver and the Maintopic, but i get an Exception: Deserialization exception handler is set to fail upon a deserialization error. If you would rather have the streaming pipeline continue after a deserialization error, please set the default.deserialization.exception.handler appropriately.

Comment: some problems with deserialization of key or value. are you sure that you send correct message (valid json)? I copied your json message and it works fine. please provide full exception stack trace to understand your problem

Comment: you can add one more stream property to skip invalid messages:
`default.deserialization.exception.handler=org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.LogAndContinueExceptionHandler`

Comment: Was my Fault, i uploaded now the Hole Message

Comment: Pasted the hole Stream as json aswell (export from landoop)

Comment: https://pastebin.com/zmANfe4b

Here the hole Log with the Exception.

I hope you can help me

Comment: as I see at https://pastebin.com/PUfhL8fK, you have `'\n'` inside json representation. I guess the problem exactly due to these characters. if you insert into source topic value as you provided in `Unformated: Value`, it will work fine

Comment: Also add `streamProperties1.put("default.deserialization.exception.handler", "org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.LogAndContinueExceptionHandler");` to skip deserialization failed messages (at least for testing purposes)

Comment: at pastebin.com/PUfhL8fK,you have `{\n  \"phenomenonTime\" : \"2017-04-03T16:08:09.000Z\" }`. Actually it means that you will get string `"{\\n  \\\"phenomenonTime\\\" : \\\"2017-04-03T16:08:09.000Z\\\" }"`.
As a workaround, you could take string from source topic and manually transform it into your required representation/map with one more `mapValues`

Comment: `Consumed<String, String> consumed = Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String()); KStream<String, String> temperatureKStream = streamBuilder1.stream("mainSourceTopic", consumed); temperatureKStream
                .mapValues((generalDetailsString) -> { ... do transformation from string ...  }`

Comment: Back in time i had the same issue where i had a Kafka Client and used a normal JSON Parser and i had to remove the first {.  
String result = record.value();
                int i = result.indexOf("{");
                result = result.substring(i);

How can i do that with kafka Streams

Comment: `KStream<String, String> temperatureKStream = ...;  temperatureKStream
                .mapValues((generalDetailsString) ->  { String updatedMessage = generalDetailsString.toString().replace("\\n", "").replace("\\", "")); 
return updatedMessage;
}`. inside `mapValues` you could do any transformations with your message e.g. replace, substring.

Comment: I am wondering why landoop add this /n.

Waht do you mean I have to do with the "manually transform it" with MapValues ?

Comment: I added my Kafka Client Example aswell, where i used Json on the same data aswell

Comment: yes, I just meant to implement your logic with substring inside `mapValues`

Comment: But now i can't use Map<String, Object>> (json)

I am so confsued

Comment: https://pastebin.com/bq5M4Z8H Here is a simple system.out.print from value. It's in the right format?

Comment: I just did a   replaceAll("\\n", "")
                        .replaceAll("\\s+", "");

and tryed to resolve Manually the JSON with JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) new JSONParser().parse(value.toString());

And I alwys get "Unexpected character ( ) at position 0. "

Comment: seems you need `details.replace("\\n", "").replace("\\", "")`, and only after that parse string